# A fairly simple SQL problem

Tags: sql

Table structure:

```
Table: People

| Name | Skill1     | Skill2     | Skill3     | Skill4     | Skill5     |
| Tom  | Cooking    | Cleaning   | Eating     |            |            | 
| Jane | Typing     | Cooking    | Sleeping   | Flirting   |            |
| John | Tennis     |            |            |            |            |
```

Where there is no skill, it is just NULL.
For some reason I'm getting 0 results using the following SQL:

```
select Name from People
where Skill1 or Skill2 or Skill3 or Skill4 or Skill5 = 'Cooking';
```

I'd expect to see Tom and Jane... but I don't, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your database table design is flawed. Skills should be a separate table that references a person table. Then you would be able to perform a simple select and join.

Comment: Don't worry that isn't my table :D I just threw in a quick example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest syntax may be this one:

```
select Name 
from People 
where 'Cooking' IN (
  Skill1,
  Skill2,
  Skill3,
  Skill4,
  Skill5);
```

Comment: @stockoverflow: reverse the logic - check the static value is in the dynamic values.

Answer (score 5):

You need each clause to be a full test:

```
select Name from People 
where Skill1 = 'Cooking'
or Skill2 = 'Cooking'
or Skill3 = 'Cooking'
or Skill4 = 'Cooking'
or Skill5 = 'Cooking';
```

Between the `where` and each `or` there has to be a full boolean test.  In your script you are just calling the column, which depending on the version of SQL you are using will having different results.

SQL Server gives this:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 An
>   expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'OR'.

Answer (score 4):

`or` doesn't work as you expect it to. Try it like this:

```
select Name from People
where Skill1  = 'Cooking' or Skill2  = 'Cooking' or Skill3  = 'Cooking'or Skill4  = 'Cooking' or Skill5 = 'Cooking';
```

Additionally, when you find yourself creating multiple columns with the same kind of data in it, like your `SkillX` columns, it's time to create an extra table. In your case, make a table `Skills`. `Skills` should contain a `Name`, referring to the `People` table, and 1 `Skill` column. For each skill that a person possesses `Skills` should contain one row. Remove the `SkillX` columns from the `People` table since those are now obsolete.